# How does Grails handle security, and why should I use a plugin?

Tags: security, session, jakarta-ee, grails

For 90% of every security-related Grails tutorial, they tell you to store your User objects in a session-scoped variable. That's all nice and easy, but I wonder if it's too good to be true, especially with plugins like [Spring Security](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) that offer many times more features.

For the simple, "I am a user and therefore I am entitled to view/edit my own domain objects" applications that I develop, I store my User objects in a session. However, this got me thinking how Grails supports J2EE security and sessions in its own implementation (it *does* use a temporary session ID in the cookie, right?). Furthermore how vulnerable is it to attacks like cookie injection and cross-site/stray JS?

I don't want to actually invest the time in learning, integrating, and maintaining a plugin for an app that might not need it, so my question is, is Grails's session implementation secure enough for simple applications, and is there a very good reason I should use a security plugin even for these trivial tasks?

On a side-note, if anyone can point me to a good OpenID/Facebook login implementation, that would be terrific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> reason I should use a security plugin even for these trivial tasks?

... on a basic level it's also trivial to use the plugin so what's there to lose? [Screencast to get you started](http://grails.org/screencast/show/11)

Comment: I've never met that screencast before. It certainly looks handy.

Comment: ...I'm reading Grails in Action now and Peter's voice is ringing in my head :-)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding security concerns I would always suggest to prefer proven and widely adopted solutions over your own rolled security implementation. Spring Security was founded in 2003 under the name Acegi and brings you more than eight years of experience and development for your security concerns.

As you already pointed to the Grails [Spring Security](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) plugin you should have a look at the OpenID plugin [Spring Security OpenID](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid) which extends the Spring Security Core and brings you the OpenID support.