# Grails Access Control and filtering results based upon User's relationship to objects

Tags: grails, hibernate-filters

What I'm after is fairly simple (conceptually):

1. A way to define user Access to objects
2. A mechanism for filtering access based on various conditions (relationships to parent, etc)

I'm exploring a combination of the Hibernate Filter plugin and a custom filter to accomplish this and I'm making some progress (not quite working yet) but I wonder if there's a better approach. The Hibernate Filter approach seems great because we can define these condition-based filters at the domain-level and enable them at runtime via a custom filter.  Does this seem like a good approach?

Looking forward to any guidance or thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Security](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core/) provides a filter chain and **lots** of facilities for maintaining users, user access, authorities, with plugins for [OpenID](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid), [Facebook](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook), [LDAP](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap)....

I've [wondered about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717250/how-does-grails-handle-security-and-why-should-i-use-a-plugin) and now I'm convinced that as far as security goes, it is always best to use a well-known implementation, not roll your own. *Especially* in the Java EE world where things are much more complicated than they should (but that's another story).

Spring Security provides a handy [tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/), [extensive documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/), and even a Grails 2.0 [screencast](http://www.bobbywarner.com/2012/01/05/jump-into-grails-2-0/), so there is no reason you shouldn't check it out!